# save readdir into a buffer in C

Tags: c, readdir

I'm using `readdir()` to read to output all the files in a directory. The problem is that I need to save the strings into a buffer. Is there any way to save the output into a buffer or file descriptor etc?

Here is my code:

```
  DIR *directory;
  struct dirent *dir;

  directory = opendir();

  while ((dir = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
  }

  closedir(directory);
```

Comment: Yes there is. But you should tell us a bit more of what you want to do exactly.

Comment: You can copy the strings into a buffer instead of printing it.

Comment: It's a part of a server/client communication, and I want to save it into a buffer of a certain size (potentially several if the input is great enough), and then send it. I have no idea on how to save the input, that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scandir [How to use scandir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402428/how-to-properly-use-scandir-in-c)

It allocates the memory for you. Here is an example

```
/**code to print all the files in the current directory **/
struct dirent **fileListTemp;
char *path = ".";//"." means current directory , you can use any directory path here
int noOfFiles = scandir(path, &fileListTemp, NULL, alphasort);
int i;
printf("total: %d files\n",noOfFiles);
for(i = 0; i < noOfFiles; i++){
    printf("%s\n",fileListTemp[i]->d_name);
```

you can modify it to suit your need . Also do not forget to free memory allocated by scandir

Comment: scandir() has 5 parameters, not 4.  as in: int scandirat(  int dirfd,
   const char *dirp,
   struct dirent ***namelist,
   int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
   int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));

Comment: I have tried to find a solution on how to save the output from this method into a char buffer[]. I have used strcat, and this works, but I think I read somewhere that it's a bad solution? Is this correct?

Comment: Also, one more question! Is it possible to call scandir from a specified directory?

Comment: are you trying to store all the elements in single buffer ?

Comment: Yeah, or (potentially) several if the size is bigger than 500.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will have to work with a data structure, like a linked list or a tree.
Here's a short example, an idea to work on:

```
 pDir = readdir(directory);
 while ( pDir != NULL ){
   strcpy(dirStruct[iCtFile]->FileName, pp->d_name);
 }
```

Looking ahead, you should consider path treatment and other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'll need to pass a directory name to `opendir()`.

This is simple example of how to read and save them into a buffer.  It doubles the pointers every time it hits the limit. Modern operating systems will clean up the memory allocated once process dies. Ideally, you should also call `free()` in case of failures.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  size_t i = 0, j;
  size_t size = 1;
  char **names , **tmp;
  DIR *directory;
  struct dirent *dir;

  names = malloc(size * sizeof *names); //Start with 1

  directory = opendir(".");
  if (!directory) { puts("opendir failed"); exit(1); }

  while ((dir = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
     names[i]=strdup(dir->d_name);
     if(!names[i]) { puts("strdup failed."); exit(1); }
     i++;
     if (i>=size) { // Double the number of pointers
        tmp = realloc(names, size*2*sizeof *names );
        if(!tmp) { puts("realloc failed."); exit(1); }
        else { names = tmp; size*=2;  }
     }
  }

  for ( j=0 ; j<i; j++)
  printf("Entry %zu: %s\n", j+1, names[j]);

  closedir(directory);
}
```